# Setting up VS Code for Java web development

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, jsp, servlets

I want to setup my pure Java web project in VS Code. My project directory looks like this:

[image: screenshot from VS Code]

```
.vscode
WEB-INF
 ..../classes/com/example/HelloWorldServlet.java
..../lib/servlet-api.jar
....web.xml
.classpath
index.jsp
```

I have added my project to **webapps** folder in tomcat installation folder and when I go to localhost:8080/manager/html I can see /Project_1 as one of the applications: [image: tomcat webapp manager]

If I go to *localhost:8080/Project_1* it shows me the contents of a body on index.jsp file, but when I edit the file it will not update, not even after tomcat restart. What am I missing? Also I have a servlet as you can see as one of my files and I specified a route for it but gives me 404  when I go on *localhost:8080/Project_1/hello*: [web.xml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZOMh.png)

Files:

- web.xml:

```xml
    <web-app>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>HelloWorldServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.example.HelloWorldServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>HelloWorldServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/hello</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

- .classpath

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/servlet-api.jar"/>
    <!-- Any other dependencies you might have -->
</classpath>
```

- index.jsp

```xml
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hello JSP</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello World from JSP</h1>
    <h1>Hello World from JSP</h1>
    <h1>Hello World from JSP</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

- HelloWorldServlet.java

```
package com.example;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.io.*;

public class HelloWorldServlet extends HttpServlet {
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("<html><body>");
        out.println("<h1>Hello World from Servlet</h1>");
        out.println("</body></html>");
    }
}
```

Comment: please put all the relevant file in the question as formatted text, not links to files/external sources

Comment: Ok, just a moment

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get hot reloading of `.jsp` files, you can install the [**Deploy**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mkloubert.vs-deploy) extension and follow the steps below.

1. After downloading the extension, add the following configuration in ***settings.json***.

   ```
       "deploy": {
           "packages": [
               {
                   "name": "frontend",
                   "description": "All files in webapp",
                   "files": [
                       "src/main/webapp/*",
                       "src/main/webapp/*/*",
                       "src/main/webapp/*.*",
                       "src/main/webapp/*/*.*",
                       "src/main/webapp/*/*/*.*",
                       "src/main/webapp/*/*/*/*.*",
                       "src/main/webapp/*/*/*/*/*.*",
                       "src/main/webapp/*/*/*/*/*",
                       "src/main/webapp/*/*/*/*/*/*.*",
                   ],
                   "exclude": [
                       "src/main/webapp/test/*"
                   ],
                   "deployOnSave": true,
                   "useTargetList": true,
                   "button": {
                       "text": "Deploy",
                       "tooltip": "Click here to deploy frontend to hotsite",
                       "targets": [ "HOTSITE" ]
                   },
               }
           ],
           "targets": [
               {
                   "type": "local",
                   "name": "HOTSITE",
                   "description": "A local folder",
                   "dir": "target/DETE/",
                   "mappings": [
                       {
                           "source": "src/main/webapp",
                           "isRegEx": false,
                           "target": "/"
                       }
                   ]
               }
           ]
       }
   ```
2. After the addition is complete, click the `Deploy` button that appears in the status bar below.

   [image]
3. Right-click on the tomcat server and select `Add Deployment`

   [image]
4. Select `Exploded`

   [image]
5. Select the **DETE** folder generated by just clicking `Deploy` in the explorer

   [image]
6. Type `http://localhost:8080/DETE` in the browser address bar and press Enter

   [image]

   *Or right-click on tomcat and select `Server Actions...` --> `Show in Browser...` --> `http://localhost:8080/DETE`*
7. Modify `.jsp` to add a line of content
   [image]
8. Refreshing the page shows the changed content.
   [image]